# How to scan network for shares with permissions granted to users which have been deleted (and then delete them)

Tags: windows, security, account

I'm looking to clean up permissions for user accounts which have been deleted.

I would like to be able to scan all top-level shares in the domain and remove those permissions.  I've taken a look at [Share Enum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897442.aspx) but it doesn't really seem to be set up for this type of activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-existance of an user can only be determined by a successful failed lookup. This means you need to be able to query AD successfully, and AD needs to respond that the user doesn't exist. You need to be sure you were able to query the whole distribution of your AD-structure. I'm not sure this is the way to go.

You can use the command `cacls` or `icacls` to list permissions and take action. But I would consider this a highly dangerous route to go. Any network error which causes failure in lookup will result in loss of unwanted files.

Instead you should consider moving users to a quarantine OU and disabling them. Then you could get a list of OU members and process that with `cacls` output.

```
Set objGroup = GetObject ("LDAP://cn=DeletedUsers, dc=your,dc=domain")
For each objMember in objGroup.Members
  Wscript.Echo objMember.Name
Next
```

Comment: I have a utility which will list out all of the accounts which have been deleted.  I could feed that into cacls for all top-level shares, but it seems that that's a bit brute-force.

Comment: You would use cacls to list files+permissions, then check against the list of deleted GUIDS (not users).